# Using select in a nested list

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

I have a nested list of the following form

```
List1 = {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, {2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, {1, 3, 4, 5, 6}, {1, 2, 4, 5, 
  6}, {1, 2, 3, 5, 6}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 6}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {1, 2, 5, 
  6}, {1, 2, 4, 6}, {1, 2, 4, 5}, {1, 2, 3, 6}, {1, 2, 3, 5}, {1, 2, 
  3, 4}, {5, 6}, {4, 6}, {4, 5}, {3, 6}, {3, 5}, {3, 4}, {2, 6}, {2, 
  5}, {2, 4}, {6}, {5}, {4}, {3}, {2}, {1}, {}, {3, 4, 5, 6}, {2, 4, 
  5, 6}, {2, 3, 5, 6}, {2, 3, 4, 6}, {2, 3, 4, 5}, {1, 4, 5, 6}, {1, 
  3, 5, 6}, {1, 3, 4, 6}, {1, 3, 4, 5}, {4, 5, 6}, {3, 5, 6}, {3, 4, 
  6}, {3, 4, 5}, {2, 5, 6}, {2, 4, 6}, {2, 4, 5}, {2, 3, 6}, {2, 3, 
  5}, {2, 3, 4}, {1, 5, 6}, {1, 4, 6}, {1, 4, 5}, {1, 3, 6}, {1, 3, 
  5}, {1, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 6}, {1, 2, 5}, {1, 2, 4}, {1, 2, 3}, {2, 
  3}, {1, 6}, {1, 5}, {1, 4}, {1, 3}, {1, 2}}
```

I want to select those sublists that have only 2 elements or 4 elements, I wanted to use

```
Select[List1,Length[#]==2||Length[#]==n-2&]
```

where `n == 6`.

However, I am getting only the set with 4 elements. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: You must not have assigned `n` its value. Make sure that the symbol `n` is black in your code. If it's blue, it doesn't have a value yet. Make sure to add `n = 6` before you run the `Select` expression and it will work fine.

Comment: With such questions, please show a short, self-contained example that reproduces the problem.  Without knowing what you did exactly, people will just start guessing about what the problem may be.

Comment: `With[{n = 6}, Cases[List1, {Repeated[_, {n - 2}] | Repeated[_, {2}]}]]`

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Example

**Code**

```
Select[list, Length @ # == 2  ||  Length @ # == 4 &]
```

or with `n`

```
n = 6;
Select[list, Length @ # == 2  ||  Length @ # == n - 2 &]
```

**Output**

> {{1, 2, 5, 6}, {1, 2, 4, 6}, {1, 2, 4, 5}, {1, 2, 3, 6}, {1, 2, 3, 
>     5}, {1, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 6}, {4, 6}, {4, 5}, {3, 6}, {3, 5}, {3, 
>     4}, {2, 6}, {2, 5}, {2, 4}, {3, 4, 5, 6}, {2, 4, 5, 6}, {2, 3, 5, 
>     6}, {2, 3, 4, 6}, {2, 3, 4, 5}, {1, 4, 5, 6}, {1, 3, 5, 6}, {1, 3, 
>     4, 6}, {1, 3, 4, 5}, {2, 3}, {1, 6}, {1, 5}, {1, 4}, {1, 3}, {1, 2}}

**Note:** `list` is your original data

Answer (score 5):

Never forget Pick for problems involving picking elements from a list.

```
data = 
  {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, {2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, {1, 3, 4, 5, 6}, {1, 2, 4, 5, 6}, 
   {1, 2, 3, 5, 6}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 6}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {1, 2, 5, 6}, {1, 2, 4, 6}, 
   {1, 2, 4, 5}, {1, 2, 3, 6}, {1, 2, 3, 5}, {1, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 6}, {4, 6}, {4, 5}, 
   {3, 6}, {3, 5}, {3, 4}, {2, 6}, {2, 5}, {2, 4}, {6}, {5}, {4}, {3}, {2}, {1}, {}, 
   {3, 4, 5, 6}, {2, 4, 5, 6}, {2, 3, 5, 6}, {2, 3, 4, 6}, {2, 3, 4, 5}, 
   {1, 4, 5, 6}, {1, 3, 5, 6}, {1, 3, 4, 6}, {1, 3, 4, 5}, {4, 5,6}, {3, 5, 6}, 
   {3, 4, 6}, {3, 4, 5}, {2, 5, 6}, {2, 4, 6}, {2, 4, 5}, {2, 3, 6}, {2, 3, 5}, 
   {2, 3, 4}, {1, 5, 6}, {1, 4, 6}, {1, 4,5}, {1, 3, 6}, {1, 3, 5}, {1, 3, 4}, 
   {1, 2, 6}, {1, 2, 5}, {1, 2,4}, {1, 2, 3}, {2, 3}, {1, 6}, {1, 5}, 
   {1, 4}, {1, 3}, {1, 2}};

With[{n = 6}, Pick[data, Length /@ data, 2 | n - 2]]
```

> ```
> {{1, 2, 5, 6}, {1, 2, 4, 6}, {1, 2, 4, 5}, {1, 2, 3, 6}, {1, 2, 3, 5}, 
>  {1, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 6}, {4, 6}, {4, 5}, {3, 6}, {3, 5}, {3, 4}, {2, 6}, {2, 5}, 
>  {2, 4}, {3, 4, 5, 6}, {2, 4, 5, 6}, {2, 3, 5, 6}, {2, 3, 4, 6}, {2, 3, 4, 5}, 
>  {1, 4, 5, 6}, {1, 3, 5, 6}, {1, 3, 4, 6}, {1, 3, 4, 5}, {2, 3}, {1, 6}, {1, 5}, 
>  {1, 4}, {1, 3}, {1, 2}}
> ```

Answer (score 4):

Just for our unanswered rate:

```
With[{n = 6}, Select[List1, Length[#] == 2 || Length[#] == n-2 &]]

With[{n = 6}, Pick[List1, Length/@List1, 2 | n-2]]
```

Try `With`: it will always help if you want to plug something in an expression fast.